# Java JFrame/JButton/Box - no button appearing

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jbutton

Class1

```
public class mainclass extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jf = new mainclass();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(new Dimension(720, 480));
        jf.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    }
    public mainclass(){
        components c = new components();
        Box b = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        for(int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(c.get(i).getWidth());
            b.add(c.get(i));
        }
        getContentPane().add(b);
    }
}
```

Class2

```
public class components extends ArrayList<Component>{
    public components(){
        JButton b = new JButton("Quit");
        b.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 200);
        b.setVisible(true);
        this.add(b);
    }
}
```

The JButton should be added to the box, which is added to the JFrame without a layout. Why isn't the button appearing?

Answer (score 1):

You are shooting yourself in the foot by using null layouts and absolute positioning.

- You give your JFrame a null layout
- and then add a component to it without specifying its size or position (the Box), and so it will have size (0, 0).
- Instead avoid use of null layout
- Learn and use the layout managers as they will help you easily create well balanced GUI's.

Better for you to describe what structure you're trying to achieve I think. Also, I would avoid creating classes that extend collections such as ArrayList. Instead it's much better to enhance by composition and not inheritance in this instance.